# Make a table with nested columns in R

Tags: r

I have a table in R that is built using this data frame:

```
Year <- c('2016','2017','2018','2016','2017','2018')
D <- c(0.6,0.57,.56,.41,.45,.85)
C <- c(.8,.9,.65,.8,.9,.65)
var <- c('a','a','a','b','b','b')
dat <- cbind.data.frame(var,Year,D,C)
```

My goal create a summary table with a header row for each year, then nest(apologies if this not the correct word here) fields D and E under said year: [desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdan1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base R, it is not quite true that you can produce the desired output.  R dataframes do not allow for  MultiIndex unless you use `ftables`. The closses you could get is using dataframes is provided by the below solutions. If you dont mind using `ftables` you could do:

```
tm <- c("D", "C") # the columns to change
a <- reshape(dat, list(tm), idvar = c("var", "Year"), dir = "long", times = tm))
ftable(xtabs(D~., a), row.vars = 1)

    Year 2016      2017      2018     
    time    C    D    C    D    C    D
var                                   
a        0.80 0.60 0.90 0.57 0.65 0.56
b        0.80 0.41 0.90 0.45 0.65 0.85
```

EDIT:
since you are using the `KableExtra` package, You could do:

```
nm <- setNames(rep(1:2, c(2, length(unique(dat$Year)))), c(rep(" ", 2), levels(dat$Year)))

library(kableExtra)
dat %>%
  reshape(idvar = "var", timevar = "Year", direction = "wide") %>%
  setNames(gsub("[0-9.]+", "", names(.))) %>%
  kable() %>%
  kable_styling("striped") %>%
  add_header_above(nm)
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: The answer you've provided solves my question. The problem is when I feed ftable into kable it stops working. Ultimately I'm trying to use kable to produce something like this: https://rfortherestofus.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/kableExtra-example.png

The page doesn't site documentation on how to the author built this, which probably should have been the first warning sign. Based on my understanding of stackoverflow, I'm going to mark your solution as correct.

Comment: @Big_Red. I just checked your comment. You seem to be using `KableEtra` package. Check my edit

Comment: Thanks! That code throws an error: Error in names(header)[header_names == ""] <- header[header_names == ""] : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a multi-row index in R.
This might work:

```
reshape(dat, idvar = "var", timevar = "Year", direction = "wide")

    var D.2016 C.2016 D.2017 C.2017 D.2018 C.2018
1   a   0.60    0.8   0.57    0.9   0.56   0.65
4   b   0.41    0.8   0.45    0.9   0.85   0.65
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work with what I'm attempting to produce: https://rfortherestofus.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/kableExtra-example.png

Answer (score 0):

An option with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = Year, values_from = c(D, C))
# A tibble: 2 x 7
#  var   D_2016 D_2017 D_2018 C_2016 C_2017 C_2018
#  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 a       0.6   0.570   0.56    0.8    0.9   0.65
#2 b       0.41  0.45    0.85    0.8    0.9   0.65
```

---

Or using `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(dat), var ~ Year, value.var = c("D", "C"))
#   var D_2016 D_2017 D_2018 C_2016 C_2017 C_2018
#1:   a   0.60   0.57   0.56    0.8    0.9   0.65
#2:   b   0.41   0.45   0.85    0.8    0.9   0.65
```